# Is there string in C?

Tags: c++, c, pic

Is there `string` in [CCS](https://ccsinfo.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=205898)?

> Can I use:

```
string myString = "My String"; // Error
```

or **NOT**?

Comment: `string` is not a datatyte in C. The header is used to wor with functions like `strcmp`

Comment: In other words: 1) `char *myString = "My String"; ` or `char[16] myString = "My String";` would be correct syntax for C, 2) `string.h` gives you the definitions for functions like [strcmp()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcmp.3.html), [strlen()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strlen.3.html), etc.

Comment: Nguyen, it's not considered "kosher" to change questions wholesale (so that the new question has nothing to do with the original, as was the case with your edit) after answers have been posted, it invalidates those answers. I have therefore rolled your changes back. Since you don't have a quota of questions, the accepted process is to just ask a different question.

Comment: Since you state you cannot post a new question, I've done it for you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59589320/get-substring-from-data-received-uart-and-put-to-lcd Please answer any comments over there and let me know which answer best solves your problem.

Comment: Nguyen, please stop making massive changes to the question, I have already asked the (totally unrelated) question for you over at the link in the previous comment. You should be looking there for activity relating to your new problem. This one is asked, answered and accepted.

Comment: I am really sorry all about that problem. I tried to ask the question, but my bad question make me canot ask everyone. So I change to improve my question without update.

Comment: I asked him to help me with the next question by updating it to the old question. Question content cannot be lost.

Comment: I ve seen your help. Thank you, @paxdiablo.

Comment: Nguyen, the intent of SO is a question and answer site where the questions are very specific and hopefully of use in future. People have tried to treat it like a conversation board in the past by evolving their questions massively and it just doesn't work. For a start, it invalidates all useful answers to date and (especially) if already answered and accepted, will not gather much interest for future answers. I'm not trying to give you a hard time, just pointing out how the site best works. And, while typing this, your previous (thank you) comment has appeared ...

Comment: ... so I guess we no longer need to discuss. Hopefully, you'll get a decent answer over at the linked question. Best of luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard `string.h` header file does *not* define a data type called `string`, it provides functions for manipulating C-style strings, which are null-terminated character arrays.

For example, you can do something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void) {
    char *myName = "paxdiablo";
    printf("Length of '%s' is %zu\n", myName, strlen(myName));
    return 0;
}
```

Note the string in that code, it's a pointer to the `paxdiablo` string literal, *not* some `string` type that the standard does not provide.

---

C++ *does* provide a `std::string` type but that's in the C++ `string` header rather than the C `string.h`. In any case, it doesn't appear from their [web presence](http://www.ccsinfo.com/ccs-product-catalog.php) that CCS provides a C++ compiler, instead focusing on the C market.

Comment: Thank you, Sir. There is another type same `string` I can use instead?

Comment: @NguyenVanThanh, you could incorporate something like http://bstring.sourceforge.net/ into your code, this supposedly gives you more power and safety than regular C strings.

Comment: I fix it, but have problem as below, can you help me? This old question have many downvote make me canot ask any one.  Thank you so much!